# How do I retry a network request using retrofit, publish relay, and rxjava by clicking a button?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, retrofit, rx-android

I am trying to use a publish relay to retry an observable chain when an error occurs. This is the implementation I am using in `kotlin`:

```
 private fun getPostsFromVM(maxRes : String) : Disposable{
        return viewModel.getPostList(maxRes).
        retryWhen { attempt -> publishRelay }.
                subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
                observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
                subscribe({//handle post response
                    Log.d("SubscribeResp",it.etag)
                    //Toast.makeText(activity,it.blogKind,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    text.text = " ${it.blogKind } \n ${it.items.get(0).title}"
                },{
                    Log.d("ApiResponseError",it.localizedMessage)
                    if (it is HttpException){
                    retryBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    val resp = it.response()
                    when(resp.code()){
                        403 -> Toast.makeText(activity,"403 Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        304 -> Toast.makeText(activity,"304 Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        else -> Toast.makeText(activity,resp.message(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }else text.text = it.message})  
}
```

Publish relay is instantiated in the `onCreate` Method. I then use a button to call the retry method:

```
retryBtn.setOnClickListener{
            publishRelay.retry(1)
        }
```

When I tested this out, I didn't get anything (I make sure there is a network error that gets called) so that I can retry by clicking the button but, nothing happens, the retry does not occur.

Comment: Can you try `publishRelay.accept(1)` instead of `publishRelay.retry(1)`.

Comment: I tried this, but i get a Networkonmainthread Exception. Also, onError from the initial request does not get called. (Breakpoints i set in onError are not reached).This means the retry button is not set to visible.